# SemaphoreSlim limit tasks

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I find myself having to loop through a lot of async calls all over the place in my code base.  The current pattern we are using is to declare SemaphoreSlim(maxcount) and then await sem.WaitAsync(), Create a new task, add it to a List and then repeat.  To control the release the new task itself has a reference to sem and does the release on final.  There is a step in there to look for and remove completed tasks.  This is a pattern that was inherited and is used for multiple different types of async calls.  As I develop new code I was hoping to simply this into a single helper class where I can just queue the work until I hit a set limit and then have to wait to add the next once a slot as freed up.

The calls are all async (as this is a 3rd party lib that we don't control).  Also, the library I maintain has to be used in both winform and asp.net processes, so keeping it async seems ideal.  The targets are usually waiting web services (5-10s range), in which we don't want to slam, but at the same time we typically have 1000's of items in the queue (3rd part has no bulk update implementation -- one element at a time type situation).

This is what I have come up with (naming is still a work in progress):

```
// Assume this is the parameter to the method we're calling over and over again
private class _ProcessArg
{
  public Guid ID { get; set; }
}

// The method that we are calling over and over again
private async Task _Process(_ProcessArg arg, CancellationToken ct)
{
  await Task.Run(() => { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(arg.ID.ToString())});
}

// The main loop where we generated the data for the call. 
private async Task _RunMainLoop(CancellationToken ct)
{
  int maxThreads = 10;
  ConcurrentQueue<Guid> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<Guid>();

  // Typically this would be the database load/whatnot
  for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
  {
    queue.Enqueue(Guid.NewGuid());
  }

  AsyncTaskMutex mutex = new AsyncTaskMutex(maxThreads);
  while (true)
  {
    Guid id;
    if (queue.TryDequeue(out id))
    {
      await mutex.QueueTask<_ProcessArg>(_Process, new _ProcessArg
      {
        ID = id,
      }, ct);
    }
    else
    {
      await mutex.DrainQueue(ct);
      break;
    }
  }
}


// Class I'm looking for peer review on
public class AsyncTaskMutex
{
  private SemaphoreSlim _sem;
  private List<Task> _tasks;

  public AsyncTaskMutex()
    : this(10)
  {
  }

  public AsyncTaskMutex(int maxTasks)
  {
    _sem = new SemaphoreSlim(maxTasks, maxTasks);
    _tasks = new List<Task>();
  }

  public async Task DrainQueue(CancellationToken ct)
  {
    await Task.WhenAll(_tasks);
    _tasks.RemoveAll(t => t.IsCompleted);
  }

  public async Task QueueTask<T>(Func<T, CancellationToken, Task> func, T args, CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken))
  {
    await _sem.WaitAsync(ct);
    try
    {
      Task task = func(args, ct);
      task.GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(_OnCompleted);
      _tasks.Add(task);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
      // Intentional ignore
      return;
    }
  }

  private void _OnCompleted()
  {
    _sem.Release(1);
    _tasks.RemoveAll(t => t.IsCompleted);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you simply need process a fixed set of work items in parallel with a fixed degree of parallelism and in an async compatible way. [Stephen Toub has written a very elegant way to do that in just a couple lines of code.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/05/implementing-a-simple-foreachasync-part-2/)

```
public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int dop, Func<T, Task> body) 
{ 
    return Task.WhenAll( 
        from partition in Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(dop) 
        select Task.Run(async delegate { 
            using (partition) 
                while (partition.MoveNext()) 
                    await body(partition.Current); 
        })); 
}
```

Your new code would be:

```
await ForEachAsync(GetWorkItems(), dop: 16, body: async item => {
 await ProcessItem(item); //TODO
});
```

There is no need to explicitly maintain a queue. But if you want to, you can du that by feeding `ConcurrentQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable()` into that `ForEachAsync` helper.

Comment: I'm going to have to give this a look.  The ability to cancel a thread or the entire process is a must, but I suspect there is a way to factor that into his implementation for reuse as well.  Usually we're talking 10-12 threads with a queue of 500k tasks.  The example is simplistic but there is a queue manager that continuously adds to it.

Comment: Yes, cancellation is easy and should be done within `ProcessItem` like you normally would do it. The loop inherently has no ability to cancel a running work item. Of course you can also test the CancellationToken inside the loop if that would work for you.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the extension method I've created.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Concurrently Executes async actions for each item of <see cref="IEnumerable<typeparamref name="T"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of IEnumerable</typeparam>
    /// <param name="enumerable">instance of <see cref="IEnumerable<typeparamref name="T"/>"/></param>
    /// <param name="action">an async <see cref="Action" /> to execute</param>
    /// <param name="maxActionsToRunInParallel">Optional, max numbers of the actions to run in parallel,
    /// Must be grater than 0</param>
    /// <returns>A Task representing an async operation</returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">If the maxActionsToRunInParallel is less than 1</exception>
    public static async Task ForEachAsyncConcurrent<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> enumerable,
        Func<T, Task> action,
        int? maxActionsToRunInParallel = null)
    {
        if (maxActionsToRunInParallel.HasValue)
        {
            using (var semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(
                maxActionsToRunInParallel.Value, maxActionsToRunInParallel.Value))
            {
                var tasksWithThrottler = new List<Task>();

                foreach (var item in enumerable)
                {
                    // Increment the number of currently running tasks and wait if they are more than limit.
                    await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();

                    tasksWithThrottler.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
                    {                            
                        await action(item).ContinueWith(res =>
                        {
                            // action is completed, so decrement the number of currently running tasks
                            semaphoreSlim.Release();
                        });
                    }));
                }

                // Wait for all tasks to complete.
                await Task.WhenAll(tasksWithThrottler.ToArray());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(enumerable.Select(item => action(item)));
        }
    }
```

Sample Usage:

```
await enumerable.ForEachAsyncConcurrent(
    async item =>
    {
        await SomeAsyncMethod(item);
    },
    5);
```

Comment: @Jamal If you read the answer, you'll see that code is well documented. If you still have any queries, feel free to ask. Also I don't think answer is always supposed to be better - I'm posting a different approach - I've used SemaphorSlim instead of Partitioner

Comment: My mistake, I didn't see it at first.  It's not very common here to see entire reviews posted as comments.

Comment: Jay, that's an interesting take on it.  I have been using the first approach with a few tweaks.  In both cases I added some additional logic for passing in a CancellationToken (so Action<T, CancellationToken) and main method CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken) (then passing on the inside to the Action<T, CancellationToken>.  The cancellation token is a little more critical for me as we might be processing 100k items and we need a mechanism for cleaning stopping them.

Comment: Yes, you can easily add the CancellationToken parameter and pass it in semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync() & Task,Run's 2nd parameter - which can be helpful to stop the task.

Comment: This rocks, I love it!

Comment: Is there anyway to test this (total currently running threads)? One question, what if we call `await semaphorSlip.WaitAsync()` inside `Task.Run()` call? Does it still fit the maximum thread rule?

Comment: This is a really great thing to share. Thanks!